# window.resize not working when creating it in a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

Why, in the console does this display the browser size after every size change (as expected):

```
window.onresize = function() {
        var width = $(window).width(); 

        console.log(width);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5r35gLrc/

But when creating it as a function and calling it, it does not?:

```
window.onresize = browserResizeAdjustments();

function browserResizeAdjustments() {
    var width = $(window).width(); 

    console.log(width);

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wxx8do60/

The reason being is I want to run this onload as well, not just when the first browser size change happens.

**Final Solution:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onresize = browserResizeAdjustments;

function browserResizeAdjustments() {
    var width = $(window).width(); 

    console.log(width);

}

// This runs it onload
browserResizeAdjustments();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

window.onresize should be a reference to a function, not the result of a function call. Try this:

```
window.onresize = browserResizeAdjustments;
```

Comment: I would never have got that! Without brackets I would have thought was referring to a var, not a function!